# Execute multiple query from a text file

Tags: java, sql, swing, file-system, jdbc

I am just wondering if this is a correct way to execute multiple query from a text file.

```
Connection conn = Utility.getConnection();
Statement stmt = null;
try{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       String fileName=chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString()+File.separator+chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
       String strLine;
       if(conn != null)
           stmt = conn.createStatement();
       while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
           if(stmt !=null){
               int rc=stmt.executeUpdate(strLine);
               if(rc == 0)
                   System.out.println("executing:  "+strLine);
           }                   
       }
       stmt.close();
       conn.close();
       in.close();
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: well you should try to execute it, and you will have a first answer.

Comment: Code it running fine but I wanted to know some expert opinion :)

Comment: It really depends on what the requirements are. Is it just to have an easy way to run a few test queries? Then it's probably fine (assuming it works). If it's for something more serious then I'm not too fond of your (lack of) error handling and I might be worried about security (even if not user supplied you might want to think twice about blindly running deletion or update queries) and atomicity.

Comment: Side note: You might want to add extra try finally blocks around the execute code. There is no guarantee that the connection or stream is closed if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas:

- Separate the GUI code from the logic.
- If you stay with your current mixed code fail fast. If `conn` is `null` there no sense to open the file or ask the user to choose one.
- `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()` returns a `File` instance, pass it to `FileInputStream` directly, don't concatenate strings. `File` contains the absolute path.
- It's a good practice to pass a `Charset` (or `"UTF-8"`) the the constructor of the `InputStreamReader`. The default could vary from system to system.
- The `DataInputStream` looks unnecessary. You can pass the `FileInputStream` to the `InputStreamReader` directly.
- Consider using [Guava's `readLines`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20com.google.common.io.LineProcessor%29).
- Maybe you want to report all executed queries, so the `if (rc == 0)` condition is unnecessary.

Plus it lacks of proper exception/error handling and resource closing as others mentioned in the comments.